# How to break a line from a very large text in a django variable?

Tags: django

I need to display large text in a table, the problem that this is done dynamically by the variable {{students.answer}}.

I tried the linebreaks but did not get the expected result.

The table currently:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in filter `linebreak`
Every line break in your text will be replaced with \n.

`{{ students.answer|linebreak }}`

[Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks)